# Let $n$ be a positive integer, Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}}{k}{n \choose k} = H_n$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation, combinatorial-proofs

Let $n$ be a positive integer,  Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{(k-1)}}{ k} {n \choose k} = H_n = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}.$

This problem was solved as an example in Titu Andreescu's Combinatorics book.  However  I do not understand the last part of the solution. 
Here is the solution given by him
[image]

I was able to understand the solution presented above, however. What I do not understand in this

[image]

For those who might want to ask what theorem 3.2(i) states,  here it is
[image]

Please someone should help me demystify this solution, Thanks in advance.

I'm not too good with Mathjax so here is the screenshot of the original problem.

[image]

Comment: You use the point $(i)$ in the Theorem 3.2 to see that the big sum is zero

Comment: This is an instant kill through integral representations. By the binomial theorem we have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}x^{k-1}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x} $$
and by integrating both sides over $(0,1)$ we get
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\binom{n}{k}&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-(1-x)^n}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x+\ldots+x^{n-1}\right)\,dx \\&=&1+\frac{1}{2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n}=H_n. \end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

He shows that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\binom{m+1}{k}=0
$$
He uses the following property $(i)$ from the theorem $3.2$

Comment: know he did that, but how did he obtain the entire expressions on that line. That is to say. How was he able to move from $\S_{m + 1} - S_m = \frac {-1} {m + 1} \sum_{k = 1}^{n+1} (-1)^k {m+1\choose k}$ to $S_{m + 1} - S_m = \frac {1} {m+1} \frac {-1} {m + 1} \sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} (-1)^k {m+1\choose k}$ ?Also.  Notice the change in the summation index.

Comment: please check the screenshots to see if you can understand my question better as I'm not goood in MathsJax

Comment: He added the sum's term corresponding to $k=0$ and also its opposite to add $0$ and let the equality unchanged.

Comment: $0^n=(1-1)^n=\sum_{k = 0}^{n} (-1)^k {n\choose k}=1+\sum_{k = 1}^{n} (-1)^k {n\choose k}$